# Centos 6.0 + Xen

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, kvm-virtualization

So now that Xen is no more in Centos' repositories, should I still use it or migrate to KVM? I have to say that I am not very inspired by KVM at the moment and I've gotten pretty familiar with XEN already so going with Citrix' XenServer sounds like a better scenario.

What are we Xen users supposed to do? It's pretty ironic since it's getting integrated in the next Linux Kernel but from RedHat's standpoint I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Well after spending a night reading on KVM I think that the transition will be less painfull than I expected. On the other hand I am also looking at LXC linux containers. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. there is a port of Xen for Centos6 (seen it discussed on centos-virt mailing list), though I doubt it's anywhere near production quality
2. what is missing from KVM that you can do with Xen that makes you lose your inspiration? When was the last time you actually tried it?

Comment: Thank's. I suscribe the lists as well and as you said, it'll take a while before we can use it.I am not familiar with the latest implementation of KVM and that's my main concern. I have tools and scripts that I use with Xen that will take quite some time to replace with KVM's equivalents. I am not saying it's an inferior platform but it will require some time that I can't find this week or month still I will need to set up a couple of production servers. I admit it's been a long time.

Comment: what do those scripts do? It's quite possible everything you're looking for is already there in libvirt or one of the management platforms - http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools

Comment: If you are working with a CPU that does not support virtualization extensions then KVM is a no go.

Comment: @zedman9991, I'm sorry, are you from the past? (C)

Comment: Or the future if you have Intel's Atom or some lightweight tablet in your life...  you get a +1 for the comment from me

Comment: it's just funny to hear about a server without VT/AMD-V in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

XEN will be back. Oracle is working on its RH6-clone (Oracle-VM/Unbreakable Linux) to make it work with XEN again. There are cookbooks out there to get XEN 4.x working with RH6 - the same should be true for CentOS 6.

And no - I would not go for KVM. It has no para-virtualization and I`ve never seen any prove that it is better or even faster that a XEN-PV.

I was in the lucky position to use SLES 10 with XEN. When SLES11 and RH6 came up and RH6 did not support XEN any more I stayed with SLES. Else I would have switched to RH because of their better support regarding (security) patches.